# Client received SOAP Fault from server: The server cannot service this request right now

Tags: java, office365, exchangewebservices, ewsjavaapi

I am creating and sending mails (set up on office 365) using exchange server. I am using EWS server in java to send mails. From a week ago, I am getting the below issue on Windows machines when sending mails.

com.sun.xml.ws.fault.ServerSOAPFaultException  -

Client received SOAP Fault from server: The server cannot service this request right now. Try again later. Please see the server log to find more detail regarding exact cause of the failure.

Can someone please advise what can be done to avoid this error?

Comment: That error generally indicates throttling eg you maybe be sending too many emails or have too many connections

Comment: Thank you. I was able to solve the issue by keeping a one second delay while creating drafts and attachments. With this, there were fewer requests at a particular time.